# How can I reduce the dimension size in a netCDF file?

Tags: arrays, r, netcdf, netcdf4, nco

I have a netCDF file

```
dimensions:
    i1 = 3 ;
    x = 11 ;
    s1 = 1 ;
    mid1 = 8 ;
    mid2 = 8 ;
variables:
    double Height(i1,x) ;
    double Temp(s1, x) ;
    short Soil(s1, x) ;
    double Liq(mid1, x) ;
```

I want to reduce the mid1 size to 3 where I remove the rest of the 5 values.

How can I do it in using `ncdf4` package or some other utility?

Comment: Is python example suitable for you?

Comment: @kakk11 I am open to it! Though I would prefer R. Thanks!

Comment: I hope ncks solution provided by Charlie Zender works for you, if not, ping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [NCO's ncks](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncks) to hyperslab netCDF files, e.g.,

ncks -d mid1,0,2 in.nc out.nc